# How Sparks are counted as GC'd?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm experiment with Parallel and Concurrency in Haskell, and come up with this problem. I have 2 functions that evaluate each element of a list in parallel:

```
    parMap' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> Eval [b]
    parMap' f [] = return []
    parMap' f (a:as) = do
       b <- rpar (f a)
       bs <- parMap' f as
       return (b:bs)

    parListWHNF :: Strategy [a]
    parListWHNF xs = go xs `pseq` return xs
      where -- go :: [a] -> [a]
        go []     = []
        go (y:ys) = y `par` go ys
```

If I use them directly, everything is just fine (all the sparks was converted):

```
    let solutions = runEval (parMap' solve puzzles)
result: SPARKS: 1000 (1000 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

    let solutions = map solve puzzles `using` parListWHNF
result: SPARKS: 1000 (1000 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)
```

But if I wrap them inside another function like this:

```
    parList' :: (NFData a) => Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
    parList' strat xs = do
      parMap' id xs          -- case #1
      -- parListWHNF xs      -- case #2
      return xs

    let solutions = map solve puzzles `using` parList' rseq
```

Then, only `case #2` works (all the sparks was converted), `case #1` results in a lot of sparks were GC'd:

```
    SPARKS: 1000 (3 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 997 GC'd, 0 fizzled)
```

Anyone can explain this plz ?